# Burn: Pass RegistrySearch results value to Custom Bootstrapper

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, burn

In my Bundle code, I'm trying to use the result of a registry search to set Variable to be used in my Custom Boostrapper:

```
 <util:RegistrySearch
  Id="ThirdPartyInstallDirSearch"
  Variable="THIRDPARTY_INSTALL_DIR"
  Root="HKLM"
  Key="SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"
  Value="OceanSoftDir"
  Result="exists"
  />

<Variable Name="THIRDPARTY_INSTALL_DIR" Type="string" Value="$(var.THIRDPARTY_INSTALL_DIR)"/>
```

But this would give an error:
Undefined preprocessor variable '$(var.THIRDPARTY_INSTALL_DIR)'

**Basically, I want to pass the result of registry search to my custom bootstrapper application.**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, `$(var.<NAME>)` is a preprocessor define from either a wxi file or from the project file `<DefineConstants>name=value</DefineConstants>` or from a `<?define?>`. You can read more about the preprocessor [here.](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/preprocessor.html)

For your issue, the registry search itself should be defining the variable. I do something similar to what you want in a bootstrapper.

```
<Fragment>
    <util:RegistrySearch
        Id="ClientInstalledCheck"
        Root="HKLM"
        Key="SOFTWARE\Client"
        Value="ClientPath"
        Result="value"
        Variable="ClientInstalled"/>
    <util:DirectorySearch
        Path='[ClientInstalled]'
        Variable='InstallFolder'
        After='ClientInstalledCheck'
        Condition='ClientInstalled' />
</Fragment>
```

And then in the products installed by the bootstrapper I will pass in the "InstallFolder" value to these installs.

```
<MsiProperty Name="INSTALLDIR" Value="[InstallFolder]"/>
```

This way if the user has installed in a non-default install location, we pick up the custom location they chose and use that instead. If the registry key did not exist, we use the default location.

I also have the InstallFolder variable defined with a default location (since my use case is slightly different than yours) as

```
 <Variable Name="InstallFolder" Type="string" Value="[ProgramFilesFolder]$(var.CompanyInstallDir)\" bal:Overridable="yes" Persisted="yes"/>
```

Where CompanyInstallDir is defined as a preprocessor variable through `<DefineConstants>` which is originally defined somewhere in an MSBuild properties file.

So to explain your issue, you are mixing preprocessor directives and Variables. In your registry search, you're using `Result="exists"` which will set the variable THIRDPARTY_INSTALL_DIR to '0' or '1'. You want to use `Result="value"`. This will put the registry location's value in the variable you define in the `Variable=""` attribute.

If you do the registry search + directory search with condition, you can properly set a variable if and only if the registry exists AND the directory is actually present on the machine and properly handle cases where it isn't but the registry still exists.

Some things you may do differently since the use case is slightly different but hopefully this sets you on the right path for doing what you need to do.